# Unity+VisualStudio не изменяется содержимое переменной при выводе

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Изучаю Unity и Visual Studio.
Я инициализировал переменную currentAge со значением 18, проверил в Unity - работает. Далее изменил значение, сохранил, но в Unity, после перезапуска проекта,  результат вывода не изменился.
При этом, если изменить название переменной и сохранить, значение при выводе уже меняется. Что с этим делать и можно ли как-то исправить?

Код прост как спичка:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LearningCurve : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentAge = 18;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(30 + 1);

        Debug.Log(currentAge);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    
    }
}
```

Такой вывод я получаю при воспроизведении:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего изменил значение переменной на другое, а вывод после сохранения и перезапуска Игры не изменился.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Во первых `currentAge` это не **переменная в методе**, а **поле класса**. Так и задумано, если у тебя два экземпляра этого компонента, у них может быть разные значения полей, не нужно из-за значения поля писать два разных класса.

Comment: Скорее всего этот экземпляр размещен на геймобджекте. Значит его поля сериализовались и сохранились в мета-файле. Меняйте значения полей в инспекторе.